# SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS as subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS returns db, name, and comment among other columns.

Why does this not work?

> select name,comment from (    SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS ) a

Comment: `show procedure status` is not a SQL statement that can be used as a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Gordon in comments, *show procedure status is not a SQL statement that can be used as a subquery.*

Here is an equivalent query to get the procedure name and comments.

Optionally, if you need procedures to be in a specific database just add this condition in `where` clause `ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'your_database'`

```
SELECT 
    ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_COMMENT
FROM
    information_schema.ROUTINES
WHERE
    ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE';
```